# Nobody cared him(into active voice)

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, phrase-meaning

Change "Nobody cared him" into active voice

Comment: Hello Teju.  Welcome to this question and answer site.  You have not asked a question.  You have written an instruction.  What is your difficulty with this problem? What do you think the answer should be.

Comment: You should say nobody cared "about" him. What's more "Nobody cared him" is already in active voice.

Answer (score 1):

*Nobody cared him* is incorrect.

*care* is intransitive and hence should not have a direct object, like *him*.

To include *him*, we need a preposition, like *about* in this example in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cared).

> Your parents are only doing this because they care about (= love) you.

We can also use the phrasal verb *care for* in a construction like this in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/care-for-sb).

> She can't go out to work because she has to stay at home to care for her elderly mother.

We could hence say

> nobody cared **about** him

> nobody cared **for** him

These 2 examples are already in active voice.